# Find max value in each of the index of a collection of integers in c#

Tags: c#, performance, loops

I have a `List<List<int>>`.
All the list will be of equal size. I need to find the max value in every index of the list.

ie if I have 100 list each of size 3. I need to find the max value at index 0,1 and 2 across the 100 items.

ie

```
Max value out of list1[0], list2[0], list3[0],......list100[0]
Max value out of list1[1], list2[1], list3[1],......list100[1]
Max value out of list1[2], list2[2], list3[2],......list100[2]
```

Need a function which accepts the `List<List<int>>` and returns an list with max value of each index. Like below

```
public List<int> FindMaxValueByIndex(List<List<int>> items)
{
}
```

Performance is a key factor that needs to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring data validation & guaranteeing the inner lists will always have the same number of elements:

```cs
public List<int> FindMaxValueByIndex(List<List<int>> items)
{
    var maxListSize = items[0].Count;

    var maxValues = new List<int>(items.Count);

    for (var index = 0; index < maxListSize; index++)
        maxValues.Add(items.Select(x => x[index]).Max());

    return maxValues;
}
```

Input:

```cs
var data = new List<List<int>>
{
    new List<int> { 5, 10, 300, 1 },
    new List<int> { 3, 24, 2, 56 },
};
```

Output:

```cs
{5, 24, 300, 56}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the question states that the lists will always be the same size, however, since a generic list of generic lists is used and a generic list of generic lists does not enforce that requirement, this code takes the safe approach of ensuring that out of bounds indices are not accessed.

```
public List<int> FindMaxValueByIndex(List<List<int>> items)
        {
            List<int> ret = new List<int>();
            var MaxListSize = items.Select(l => l.Count).Max();
            for(int i = 0; i < MaxListSize; i ++)
            {
                ret.Add(items.Where(l => l.Count > i).Select(l => l[i]).Max());
            }
            
            return ret;
        }
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PvcFoj)

Comment: Unless I am missing something, your code evaluates the expression `items.Select(l => l.Count).Max()` on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I suppose that could be a small performance hit that could be rectified with a variable.

Comment: Bold statements like "Lists themselves are not very performant." and "would recommend using arrays rather than lists" require some clarification and links back those statements up. (And "All the list will be of equal size." mean there is no need to check if size is correct on every element)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, this answer does not (nor has it ever) made a references to lists being/not being performant. You are referring to a different answer which I deleted when I realized I was completely off-base. My recommendation regarding the array was based on an incorrect assumption that I originally had that the list would always have 3 integers. I forgot to remove it - I have done so now. I have now also addressed why I check the size of the list even though the question indicates that they will always be the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend such approach using LINQ methods :)

```
private static int[] FindMaxByIndex(List<List<int>> lists)
{
    var listLength = lists
        .Select(x => x.Count)
        .Distinct()
        // If all lists are of equal length
        // this should contain single element.
        // Otherwise this would throw exception - 
        // this is validation.
        .Single();

    var maxesByIndex = new int[listLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < listLength; i++)
    {
        maxesByIndex[i] = lists
            .Select(x => x[i])
            .Max();
    }

    return maxesByIndex;
}
```

Comment: The answer asks for a return value of `List<int>` :)